# Get rid of attribute alignment when formatting html/aspx files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, resharper

When I have a tag (in this case server side) like

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTemplates" AutoPostBack="True"
    DataValueField="TemplateID" DataTextField="TemplateName"
    OnDataBound="ddlTemplates_OnDataBound"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTemplates_SelectedIndexChanged"
    runat="server" Width="250px" CssClass="dropdown"/>
```

and I format the document with

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

the tag will get its attributes aligned like

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTemplates" AutoPostBack="True"
                  DataValueField="TemplateID" DataTextField="TemplateName"
                  OnDataBound="ddlTemplates_OnDataBound"                                          
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTemplates_SelectedIndexChanged"
                  runat="server" Width="250px" CssClass="dropdown"/>
```

How do I get rid of that attribute alignment? I would prefer to have the "one indentation level" format.

Answer (score 0):

Search the ReSharper options for 'Attributes indenting', You should find 2 instances each for HTML, XML and XML Doc Comments. Try setting them one at a time to 'Single indent' rather than 'Align by first attribute' to see which will fix your formatting.